# Limit results to last 10

Tags: php, mysql

How can I display only the LAST 10 results from a mysql query?

I want anything prior to the last 10 results to be ignored when the results are output.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM graphs WHERE sid=2 ORDER BY id");
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $graph_id = $info['id'];
    $graph_info = $info['labels'];
    $graph_fig = $info['figures'];

    echo "<label>" . $graph_info .":<span style='background-color: #06F;'>" . $graph_fig . "</span></label>";
}
?>
```

*EDIT* 
I forgot to mention that the results must be displayed in ASCENDING order sorted by the id column.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM graphs WHERE sid=2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) g ORDER BY g.id
```

Fetching last 10 records but resultset still in asc order.

Comment: Damn! This is always the problem I have when answering fresh posts, pipped to the post. :) This IS the answer you are looking for.

Comment: perfect solution. reverse order limit 10 than reverse the result!

Comment: Impressive! Reverse and reverse

Answer (score 5):

Order descending:

```
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM graphs WHERE sid=2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Explanation: by default results in an ORDER BY are sorted by ascending (ORDER BY ASC). By specifying descending (DESC) they are sorted in reverse order, the LIMIT 10 then takes the top 10 results.

Comment: That limits to the FIRST 10 results. I want the LAST 10

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right. But I don't want them displayed in reverse order. How would I flip the order?

Comment: @3rror404 store them in array with id as a key and  ksort() it

Comment: @Col shrapnell, that's just silly. You can just bracket them in another `select * from (-insert select from the answer here-) s ORDER BY s.id ASC` and you're done.

Comment: @Johan nothing silly in sorting an array. that's just one line. As for the mysql, I *hope* it does a filesort for this query not in the file actually.

Answer (score 3):

```
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

at the end of your query. It will order your ids descending and therefore the first result will be the newest