# MySQL show results with inverted order?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the last 5 results, that's why I order them by Date DESC but I need to display the results from older to newer. How can I do this?

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Badges WHERE UID = '$user' ORDER by Date DESC LIMIT 5"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    { 
    print "<img class='badge' title='" . $row['Site'] . "' src='http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://" . $row['Site'] . "?defaulticon=1pxgif' />";
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit results to last 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306843/limit-results-to-last-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM Badges WHERE UID = '$user' ORDER by Date DESC LIMIT 5) 
    t ORDER BY Date
");
```

Also:
Please use mysql_real_escape_string (http://at2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for the variable $user. Depending on where you get that from it could be a security leak through sql injection.

Comment: in fact, it doesn't matter where you get that from

Comment: @YourCommonSense: In fact, it depends: if the variable is set 2 line before, there is no security issue. The security issue is only if $user come from the client somehow and without a deep check on it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

$results = array_reverse($results);

foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo $row['Site']; // etc
}
```

Manual link: http://php.net/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) doesn't take the array by reference. You'd need to assign the returned array somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually order a second time in the same query.

I assume that you have an auto incrementad id (I'll call it 'EntryId' in this example) and then you hopefully should get what you need?

```
SELECT * FROM Badges WHERE UID = '$user' ORDER by Date DESC, EntryId ASC LIMIT 5
```